Making a Cinemagraph in Blender 4
I'm completely new to Blender and I'd like to make a cinemagraph from a video in Blender 4.1. I've found a few tutorials (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RY6ZPt42b8) but none for Blender 4. I've tried to follow the steps and adapt it to Blender 4, but I can't even find where the 'clip' menu is (the Blender manual isn't very descriptive here).
Can anyone point me in the right direction (even just where I can find the clip menu...)? Has anyone made or know of a tutorial for this? Thanks!
edit: I've realized I need to be in the 'movie clip editor', not the 'video sequence editor'. I'm still confused on how to go into the node editor after rendering the still image frame (about 1:00 in the tutorial video I mentioned)

ah I realized I need to be in the the "movie clip editor", not the "video sequence editor"

Oh wow, that's a really old tutorial... so many things have changed since then. Have you done newer tutorials as well to get at least familiar with basic Blender and what the different editor windows are for? This might really help even with such outdated videos. For example, the Node Editor he is using in the video: there he tells you to enable Use Nodes and Backdrop and then he gets a Render Layer node connected to a Composite node. These settings and nodes are nowadays found in the Compositor, which you should have come across in newer tutorials on rendering and compositing.

I've just started going through newer tutorials -- thanks for the suggestions!
